# Using transformRequest to convert string to usable output from $http.get request?

Tags: json, angularjs, http, cookies, web-applications

I have a web app that sends an $http.get request, which upon success, returns a plain-text string (not JSON) in the following form: "Hello!". I would like to not have to alter the back-end, and was wondering if there is some way I can change my $http's transformRequest attribute to handle the fact that it is receiving a string instead of JSON. Right now I am receiving the current error prior to altering transformRequest:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token H
```

This has to do with the return value (the first letter is 'H') and I assume it's because it wants a JSON object but is receiving a string. So my question is: is there something I can alter on the front-end (in the $http.get) to handle only receiving a string in return instead of JSON object?

Also I'm sure there's a better way to phrase the question title, so edits are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I immediately figured this out after posting. Because angular's $http.get is expecting a JSON object, its default 'transformResponse' function tries to parse it as JSON. All I needed to do was override the transformResponse to simply return the data that I spit back in it's basic form, like so:

```
var request = $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/message',
  headers: {'token': _userToken},
  transformResponse: function(data) {
    return data;
  }
});
```